# How to generate a printable label with information on a table or database?

Tags: php, printing, wordpress

I'm working for a magazine that needs to generate some labels to put on the magazines they send. We're using wordpress, and we have a table that holds ous suscribers information (address, name, what kind of suscription, etc.)

How or what would I use in order to create a printable label using this database info, so we can put it in the printed version of the magazine?

I thought of PHP, or generating a PDF or .doc archive.

Also using something with Google docs and Google print but I feel this would be adding uneccesary steps.

Comment: javascript has the function for printing the data/label you want. just a little PHP and CSS in it in order make it successful.

Comment: What function would it be?

Comment: just "window.print()", that's all. just add a little bit CSS and right HTML format to have a nice output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Advanced custom fields** plugin to store the address,name and everything in database.Create a page for print labels with labelprint template.Stored details can be retrieved and printed using any label generator eg.FPDF. Label print template must include the fpdf class files. Hope it helps

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

http://fpdf.de/downloads/addons/29/